# display precedence of elements with position absolute

Tags: css

Suppose I have 3 elements as in

```
<style>
    div#div1{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: green;
    }


    div#div2{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10;
        top: 10;
        background: blue;       
    }


    div#div3{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20;
        top: 20;
        background: red;
    }

</style>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Now, I am getting `div3` is covering all other `div`. Is there a CSS rule that gives one element precedence over other element with `position: absolute`?

Comment: What do you mean by precedence? The code is doing exactly as it's told. :)

Comment: @Kyle I ment that if I want to display `div1` over other `divs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do as you wish add a z-index to all the divs:

```
div#div1
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: green;
    z-index: 3;
}


div#div2
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: blue;     
    z-index: 2; 
}

#div3
{
height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Also remember to use units when defining top and left values, you had `top: 10;` ten what? :)

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/XBjD3/1/).